# Why is the average of $f$, $\bar{f}$, defined as $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration, summation, definition, intuition, average

I have [found](https://web.archive.org/web/20220723102118/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function) the equation for the average of a function to be
$$
\bar{f} = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x
$$
however, this equation doesn't make complete sense to me. I interperet it as being the same as
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f\left(a + i\frac{b-a}{n}\right)
$$
This equation would blow up to infinity, since there is an infinite quantity of numbers larger than 0 that are being summed.

The average of a set of numbers is found by adding them up and then dividing the sum by the quantity of numbers added. So, for $n$ numbers, individually represented by $x_i$, their average would be
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i
$$
The way that I understand the first equation, the $\frac{1}{b-a}$ would only remove the $\mathrm{d}x$ from the integral. Each $\mathrm{d}x$ represents a ininitely small interval; if you were to add up the infinite number of these $\mathrm{d}x$'s you would end up with a total value of the full interval $b - a$; therefore, in the original equation, to remove the summed $\mathrm{d}x$'s we simply divide out $b - a$; however, this does not account for the sum of $f(x)$ over the interval $b-a$. When the integral equation is calculated I understand its result as simply the sum of $f(x)$ over the interval. How is it not this? (I know that it can't be, as an infinite sum of numbers larger than 0 would always go to infinity, but I don't understand why it is not.)

If I were to construct an equation to yield the average of a function I would write the following
$$
\bar{f} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(a + i\frac{b-a}{n}\right)
$$
How would this get turned into the first equation?

I understand the problem in terms of another definition that states that the average of a function would yield the same area under the curve as that of the original function over the same interval
$$
\int_a^b\bar{f}\mathrm{d}x = \int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{d}x
$$
but I just cant understand the intution behind the original equation.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(a + i\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$, and not $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(a + i\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$ as you claim.

Comment: *"an infinite sum of numbers larger than 0 would always go to infinity"* Not necessarily. Eg, $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac1{2^i}$$ isn't infinite.

Comment: @MartinR ah okay this is where my confusion is stemming from, then. I currently can't see how those two are equal, and I also don't understand why it is not equal to the second sum that I mentioned.

Comment: @PM2Ring Noted! Although, I am unsure of what the more proper way of stating what I intended would be.

Comment: The Riemann sums for the integral are $\frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(a + i\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$, since $\frac{b-a}{n} $ is the distance between the values where the function is evaluated. Now divide that by $b-a$ ...

Comment: @MartinR Ah of course. That explains it perfectly! thank you!

Comment: @MartinR, you have good comments, it would be nice if you could put a complete answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinR alright sure! I was actually waiting for you to make your comment your own answer; I didn't want to steal any internet points from you ;P

Comment: @PM2Ring, well in your example, the value $\frac{1}{2^i}$ is not ' a number larger than zero" - I guess that the  saying "adding  values > 0 infinitely must lead to an infinite number" is correct.

Comment: @NoChance What do you mean? $\frac1{2^i}>0$ for all (finite) $i$. The expression I wrote earlier is shorthand for $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac1{2^i}$$

Comment: @PM2Ring, I thought by your example that you wanted to provide a case where summing positive numbers to infinity is not always finite. Pardon me if I got it wrong :)

Comment: To make things more interesting, consider looking at the Mean function or Expected Value function for a continuous variable E(x). I guess more thought is required to link these concepts to the result you have. This is just a thought, I may have wondered so far!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [“right Riemann sum”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Right_Riemann_Sum) of $f$ over $[a, b]$ with the partition $a = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = b$ is
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_n) (x_n - x_{n-1}) \, .
$$
For equidistant partition points $x_k = a + k (b-a)/n$ this is
$$
 \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(a+ k\frac{b-a}{n})\, .
$$
If $f$ is Riemann-integrable, then any sequence of Riemann sums whose maximum width converges to zero, converges to the Riemann integral:
$$
 \int_a^b f(x) \, dx =  \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(a+ k\frac{b-a}{n}) \, ,
$$
so that the “average” is
$$
\tilde f = \frac{1}{b-a }\int_a^b f(x) \, dx =  \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(a+ k\frac{b-a}{n}) \, .
$$
So the average is (as one might expect) the limit of the arithmetic mean of the function values at $n$ equidistant points if $n$ tends to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Does it perhaps make more sense like this?
$$
\bar{f} = \frac{\Big(\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x \Big)}{b-a}
$$
On top we have an integral representing the area-under-the-curve between points a-and-b, and in the denominator we have the length from a-to-b.  This is essentially dividing the total area by it's total width to get an average height.

Comment: Personally, I can't get the formula yet. However, your explanation makes geometrical sense only maybe for square or rectangle shapes! Maybe if one considers the Physics applications such as speed, distance and acceleration together with the meaning of the area under the curve of such functions, the concept can be more clear.

Comment: @NoChance Does that mean your issue in the main question lies more in understanding an integral as "the area under the curve" in-general more so than how "this formula defines the average" in-particular?

Comment: I get the concept of integration and limited integral meaning well. The concept of the average and its relationship to limited integral is a bit tricky for me in the mathematical sense. However, it is a bit more mild from physical perspective as in here: https://math24.net/rectilinear-motion.html

Comment: @NoChance "...your explanation makes geometrical sense only maybe for square or rectangle shapes!" Maybe this is the issue.  All I am trying to say is that $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ defines a shape with an area (even if it is hard to compute exactly 'how big' that area is for now), and that $b-a$ defines a length.  So, the definition of $\bar{f}$ is just a constant function with height value just right to satisfy that the area of $\bar{f}$*(b-a) is equal to the area defined by $\int_a^b f(x) dx$.  That concept of $A_1=A_2$ is all I'm trying to get across.

Comment: I guess you may be close the core concept which I don't really get well. Why are we using "area" when we want a sum of function values: $f(a)+f(a+dx)+f(a+2dx)+....+f(a+(n-1)dx)+f(b)$ where dx --> 0....? We want to sum all the function values at each point between a and b....Where does the concept of the area come from (that is me wondering)! I will review the Fundamental Theory of Calculus again some time.

Comment: @NoChance The total area is what we want to know.  However, if the function is more complicated than a box or a triangle, then computing the *exact* area is harder than just saying $A=WxH$ like we would for a rectangle or $A=BxH/2$ for a triangle, and so we resort to slicing the total area into many smaller strips and computing the area of those individual strips.  We approximate the area of each strip based on it's width $(b-a)/n$ multiplied by it's height at that location $f(a+k (b-a)/n)$ (where k<n is which strip we're looking at).

Comment: The *magic* of calculus is the fact that this dumb "just keep slicing it up into thinner slices!" plan actually works out to the *exact* precise answer when correctly carried out to the infinite/infinitesimal limit.

Comment: Limited integral result can be interpreted as the area under the curve. I have no problem with this concept. What I need to educate myself about is: why does limited integral represent the "sum of function values for the infinite points in the range [a,b]"? This property does not look obviously related to the concept of "area". This concept is the core of the OP question, not the area.

Comment: @NoChance Reread my sentence about "the area of those individual strips" again carefully.  The f(x) value at each point represents a height, but each strip also has an infinitesimal width! That is how each strip has an individual area that relates back to the total area!

Comment: Well, this makes sense - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your last limit (which is correct) is nothing but the limit of the  Riemann sums for the integral representing the average (that is, including $b-a$).

Comment: okay, but my original question remains unanswered. How do we account for the infinite sum in the first integral? why does the answer not blow up to infinity in some way? when we remove the infinitesimal widths that create the slices of area, how does this not simply result in an infinite sum?

Comment: If $f$ is a nice function (say, continuous on $[a,b]$), its integral is a finite number. You are adding infinitely many infinitesimal quantities, namely $f(x)dx$, getting a finite result in the end. I am not sure if you understand this idea. This happens because the size of the addends and their amount balance each other. For example, $1/2+1/2=1$, $1/3+1/3+1/3=1$, etc. You can increase the number of addends, reducing accordingly their size, and you get $1$ in the limit, that is $\int_0^1 dx=1$. If your infinitesimals are too small, the sum is zero, $\int_0^1dx^2=0$.